# set background Color of view on List and Save when scrolling

Tags: java, android-studio

```
lv_monsterLayout.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     view.setBackgroundColor(GREEN); 
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObXTh.png)
This works to set the background color but once I scroll up the color goes away,any help as to how I can save the color of the item i clicked when scrolling would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Add a field `color` in your Monster model, set `color` on item click and while rendering check the color value and set the view color accordingly.

Comment: I set the color field. Do i then use the same method i used before to set the color on item click?

Comment: can u show me any examples or point to anything that might help?

Answer (score 0):

In the adapter class, I did

```
oneMonsterLine.setBackgroundColor(p.getColor());
```

I then went to my `Monster class`

```
p.setColor(WHITE);
```

Now, I can go to item click

```
lv_monsterLayout.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                 adapter.getItem(position).setColor(GREEN);
                 Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: position" + position);
                 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
             }
         });
```

I'm sure there's a better way but this got the job done feel free to drop any easier way of doing this.